# xpath - can not extract user post

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to web crawling as well as xpath. However, I am trying to crawl the following website: https://sabobic.blogabet.com/

Basically, I want to extract all "feed_pick_analysis", i.e., all text content which belongs to each post. 
I cannot use the statement bellow, because the ID is changing dynamically.

```
xpath('.//div[@class="feed-pick-title"]/div[@class="col-xs-12 _text-more feed-analysis"]/div[@id="feed_pick_analysis_27759116"]/p').extract()
```

Thus, I tried to use the following statement:

```
xpath('.//div[@class="col-xs-12 _text-more feed-analysis"]/div[@contenteditable="false"]/p').extract()
```

However, I am not even getting any data or tag responded by the website... What is my mistake?

[EDIT] This is the html I am working on:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 _text-more  feed-analysis">
                <div contenteditable="false" id="feed_pick_analysis_27759116">
                    <p>Cant verify asians because nothing is working on this site.<br>
<br>
Game is available in IBC,ISN,SBO<br>
<br>
Game on neutral ground.<br>
<br>
No home advantage for Persipura and thats big minus for them today.<br>
<br>
So Persija will have many fans on the stands, supporting them, so thats more home game for Persija.<br>
<br>
They sign some quality players(Aryanto) and&nbsp; foreigners Xandao and spanish playmaker Tomas who seems to be best player in the league.<br>
<br>
Big value on Persija +0.25 and DNB.<br>
<br>
Fair odds Persija ML @2.10 and dnb @1.50. GL!</p>                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding margin-top-10">
                    <small class="last-edit "><em>
                                                last edited: Wed, Sep 11th, 2019, 09:47                    </em></small>
                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the html of one of the posts you are working with?

Comment: Done. But you can find the website here: https://sabobic.blogabet.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your XPath expression more flexible you can ignore the number in the last @id value. Also note that your expression was missing a space between `_text-more` and `feed-analysis` - it has to be `_text-more  feed-analysis`.

```
.//div[@class="col-xs-12 _text-more  feed-analysis"]/div[contains(@id,"feed_pick_analysis")]/p
```

I merely removed the first `div` because it was not part of the sample HTML. Add it again, if the expression is not specific enough.